# Identifying hue, brightness and chroma of color and reaction time

Tags: terminology, visible-light

If someone knows how identify hue, brightness, and chroma of color, please let me know.

I am a PhD student at Educational Linguistics UNM.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of identifying colours is by matching them to a Pantone colour. Pantone is as near as there is to an industry standard. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone for details. You can buy a swatch of colours from Pantone, then you compare your colour with the swatch to identify the nearest Pantone colour and get the cirresponding HSB values from the Pantone data.

Note that not all Pantone colours can be identified with hue, saturation, brightness values as the HSB system can't describe every possible colour. Still, you'd get pretty close.

If your doing some experiment that you plan to publish, have a look at the literature to see what standards people use for defining colour. Pantone is standard in the publishing business, but it's possible researchers in your field use some other standard.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is how to place a given colour in the HSV [colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorspace). The study of colorspaces is a whole field in itself, and the most relevant colorspace depends on your application. [HSV and HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colorspaces are built to be more intuitive than the more technical RGB. The wikipedia page linked above contains the formula to convert from RGB to the HSV value, as well as [swatches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Swatches).